# Is there a way to increment QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Is there a way to increment a QString in C++- something like:
    `QString str("a");`
    `str++;`
`qDebug()<<a; //Here i want letter "b"`

**EDIT:** Yes, basically i want to increment a one letter but incrementing longer string would be good.

Comment: somehow I am worried why someone would want to increment strings. Please dont say you work at whatsapp and wanna try ROT13 for encryption

Comment: I don't have Qt, and can't test this, but does the following work?  `str[0].unicode()++`

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley QString offers toAscii() giving a c-style char back... that you can abuse in any char evilish incremental way ;-)

Comment: @Najzero I don't :) The letters are for scenarios. So if app won't work on scenario 'a' it should go to scenario 'b' and then 'c' etc.

Comment: well then simply use QString::toAscii (giving you a char), increment that char value and then recreate a QString via QString::fromAscii(). Its evil, but in your case acceptable. Edit: of course only for the last letter of your scenario via QString("scenario%1").arg(QString::fromAscii( char value ) )

Comment: @user891908 Why are you using a `QString` then and not just a simple `enum`?

Comment: @Najzero: Yes, I noticed that function too.  But I also noticed that `unicode()` returns by reference, and if that reference is directly into the string data, as I suspect, then the implementation is much simpler.  Qt's native encoding is UTF-16, where 'a' and 'b' are adjacent just as they are in ASCII. So, I don't see any reason to convert it to ASCII the way you are suggesting.

Comment: I use QT5 and toAscii seems to be depreciated. so for now i can do `qDebug()<<(char)(++str[0].unicode());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really increment a string because you would first have to define how that would work. For example, where would the values wrap arround.

You can increment the characters though, but even this will only work for meaningful character sequences:

`str[0].unicode()++;`

EDIT: reaction OP comments

If you just want to switch between scenarios, this is the code you wan to use:

```
enum Scenarios { ScenarioOne, ScenarioTwo, ScenarioThree, ScenariosCount };

Scenarios var = ScenarioOne;
var++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't increment or decrement a QString because the ++ and -- operators are not defined for that class, and there is no clear concept of what incrementing a string might mean (while it might be clear to you, it is not clear enough to make it part of the standard Qt library).

What you could do is create a subclass of QString, then implement operator++() and operator--(). With such a subclass, you would retain all the features of a standard QString, while having it behave exactly as you want for incrementing and decrementing.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) values for each character and concatenante them to the string

Comment: Notice that ASCII has nothing to do with it - `QString` works with Unicode (it contains `QChar`s).

Comment: Why is everyone upvoting this? This answer doesn't make any sense for `QString`.